# How to use the navigation-policy-decision-requested signal in Python Webkit

Tags: python, webkit

How can I use the [navigation-policy-decision-requested](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-navigation-policy-decision-requested) (or equivalent) in association with webkit_web_policy_decision_ignore()?

The following is a small outtake form my code (the rest is just a wrapper and settings etc):

```
def check(view, frame, req, nav, policy):
    webkit_web_policy_decision_ignore(TRUE)
...
view.connect("navigation-policy-decision-requested", check)
```

When I load a new page this error is returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "browser.py", line 17, in check_exec
    webkit_web_policy_decision_ignore(TRUE)
NameError: global name 'webkit_web_policy_decision_ignore' is not defined
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that if a certain address have been given, actions will be taken to prevent it from loading via Python. Any suggestions are welcome in the comments and any additional information you may need will be provided upon request.

Now I'm new to Python so please be specific in your answer, criticism  and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using pygtk, try policy.ignore().

The object names are mapped slightly differently in pygtk. In python shell you can try after executing from gi.repository import WebKit

```
print dir(WebKit)
```

to find corresponding object and in your case

```
help(WebKit.WebPolicyDecision)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I couldn't really work it out though. I found that the webkit.WebPolicyDecision.ignore() probably would work but it requires some argument. I just tried giving it true and the return is posted down below. I've tried to figure out how to read about it and such but with no success, it simply return more errors. I'm new to Python so please excuse my ignorance :) ||| 

`TypeError: descriptor 'ignore' requires a 'webkit.WebPolicyDecision' object but received a 'bool'`

Comment: Can you please check https://github.com/nhrdl/notesMD/blob/master/notesmd.py. This is my code and it does work in this code.